# Twilio autopilot collect field types

Tags: twilio

I am looking for a way to collect information using Autopilot that does not fit into a built-in field type. I would like to collect a street name and a brief description of what the caller is calling about.

For the street address, I have tried building a custom type, but it only understands street names that I have explicitly listed. For example, if I specify Main Street, autopilot understands "Main Street", but not "Third Street".

For the second type, I just need to capture whatever the caller says and store it, similar to how a gather works in programmable voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the street address field, you need to add several samples (10-20+) to your custom field type as it uses machine learning to determine if it is a valid answer or not.

Regarding the description field, Twilio shipped the ability to do that into their Autopilot public beta this week so if you don't define a type in the question, it will just collect free-form input. The documentation for that can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect).

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the free form input was added since I originally posted, this will add a lot more flexibility to the assistants.